# saving password in cpp application

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-linux

Working on a `Qt` application on embedded linux which requires to store the username, password kind of sensitive information.

I'm currently using `QStringLiteral` to store this info. Is this safe to do? These aren't visible when ran against `strings` binary. What are the available options / solutions?

`SqlCipher` is available but again it needs a password / key. Any suggestions

Comment: If somebody can read your binary, they can work out the credentials. QStringLiteral will probably just store it as a UTF-16 string. Does your embedded platform have some kind of secure enclave you can use?

Answer (score 2):

You should never store passwords! There is no way to do that securely, not in Qt nor in anywhere else! 
I would recommend you to generate a random number/salt, add the password from the user and run a secure hash on that data. For example MD5, or even better SHA1 (thanks to Ted Lyngmo). Store the result. Then you can even take a plain text file as it is very hard to get from that data back to the original password.

If security is not that big for you, you could use something like:

```
QString result = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash((password+salt),QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());
```

and safe the result in QSettings.

Comment: And how does the OP's program get the password back?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend MD5 anymore. SHA1 perhaps since it's an embedded system, otherwise SHA256, but +1.

Comment: It shouldn't be able to get the password back itself. Noone should. Whenever it's about to verify someones password, it'll use the salt+the provided password and then compare the two hashed results.

Comment: @manuell Have a look at the comment from Ted Lyngmo: The program should never be able to get the password back! No one should ever be able to do this.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You are right, MD5 is not that secure anymore and I also would prefer SHA1. I will edit my answer.

Comment: AFAIK SHA is also not good for hashing paswords, as it is a "fast hash" algorithm (which eases the attacks). You should use hashing schemes suitable for passwords, like bcrypt.

Comment: @xMutzelx Then, maybe, just maybe, your answer is not an answer to the OP's question...

Comment: @axalis yes, bcrypt could perhaps be an even safer alternative.

Comment: @manuell I don't see anything in OP's question demanding that the passwords should be retrievable in cleartext once they have been stored."_sensitive information_", "_Is this safe_" and "_SqlCipher_" makes me think OP actually wants to store the passwords in a reasonably safe manner. Even if that had not been the case, pointing out the errors in cases like this is just the right thing to do.